# Edit a Kubernetes pod to see failures on that particular pod not for all pods in the deployment

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-application-insights, azure-aks

Not able to edit a running pod, I want to see failures on this particular pod. Is it possible to edit a running pod which is already receiving requests?

I tried editing the deployment on which the pod is, but it is making changes on all the pods.
A single pod in the deployment should be failed. Is there a way to change a single pod?

Comment: kubectl delete pod podname

Comment: `I want to see failures on this particular pod.` --- Explain this a bit.

Comment: podA is running with 500 requests, I want to edit podA so that I can see 1000 requests where it has 500 failed requests in that 1000.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to edit a running pod which is already receiving requests?

No.  See the [Kubernetes API reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/workload-resources/pod-v1/): most of the fields in a PodSpec and a Container are labeled "cannot be updated", including the command and environment variables.

If you want one replica behind your Service to be failing, one option is to create a second Deployment with the same set of labels.  The Service will match both Deployments' Pods and send requests to all of them, but since there are now two separate Deployments, they can have different configuration.

If you are using a service mesh like Istio, that comes with more sophisticated routing rules and includes the ability to inject errors, but that's somewhat beyond the scope of this answer.